# cygwin doesnt see winreg, trying to build faster rcnn

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

After identifying the previous missing module which is the *numpy* module. It does not recognize where is the *winreg* module. Using **CPU_MODE_ONLY** to **install** *py-faster-rcnn* in *Cygwin*.

**ERROR LOG:**

```
 $ make
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/cygdrive/c/py-faster-rcnn/lib/setup.py", line 231, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/cygdrive/c/py-faster-rcnn/lib/setup.py", line 200, in build_extensions
        customize_compiler_for_nvcc(self.compiler)
      File "/cygdrive/c/py-faster-rcnn/lib/setup.py", line 68, in customize_compiler_for_nvcc
        import winreg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
    make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you seen the notice at https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn ?

Comment: Visited this link beforehand, but may i ask what notice are you specifically talking about?

Comment: I mean `py-faster-rcnn has been deprecated. Please see Detectron, which includes an implementation of Mask R-CNN.`